# PC will not post after shut down/sleep. PC will post again if psu is switched off for a while

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply

Specs:

- Operating System: Windows 10 Home 64-bit (10.0, Build 19045)
  (19041.vb_release.191206-1406)
- System Model: X570 AORUS ELITE
- BIOS: F37d (type: UEFI)
- Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 5600X 6-Core Processor
- Card name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER
- MEM: 4x G.Skill F4-3200C16-8GTZR
- PSU: Corsair RM750

Problem:
If I shut down/sleep my PC and try turning it on again it will no longer POST. The system will light up as well as all peripherals but there will be no display. A workaround I found but dont know why works is that if I switch off the PSU and leave it for a while then turn everything on again the PC will post again, however this is not consistent and I sometimes have to switch off the PSU multiple times before succeeding.

Other symptoms:

If I open the system to a no POST screen, the KB&M will light up then light off before lighting on again, this only happens to the KB&M

If I open the system to a no POST screen and try to power the system off via the front panel the system will power off but the lights on the fans and the lights on the mobo stay on. Everything else is powered off; peripherals, ram, monitors etc. are all dark, only the chassis fans and mobo have lights.

Comment: POST = Power On Self Test, i.e. the tasks that are done during the initial textual information when you turn on the power. This will not happen when the computer is put into "sleep"  mode.

Comment: Do you have another computer? You may try to swap the battery of the motherboard. I had strange issue like this when I had a dead battery.

Comment: As Hannu noted, this is not a POST issue because hibernating or sleeping a computer does not power it off. Forcibly powering the computer down by switching the PS loses the memory-saved data being preserved by sleep mode and is an acceptable HARDWARE work around, but it works by damaging the software. You should perform normal sleep mode fixes by checking for and updating any and all drivers, and checking your Event Viewer for events surrounding the failures.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I misunderstood that POST is term used to describe the monitors successfully displaying signal when a system is turned on. I was hoping to clarify that the blank displays occurs both when I shut down or sleep the computer. I will check the event viewer as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested I looked into event viewer checking the timestamp closest to when I attempt boot up. I saw multiple errors pointing to the same thing

*The description for Event ID 14 from source nvlddmkm cannot be found*

Solution I found was to use DDU to remove current gpu drivers and reinstall them again, so far I no longer face the original problem I described.